# Cloning an object into a list with several values changed for each item

Tags: java, list, reference

I'm trying to get my code to clone an `OutputData` object called `primitive` into a list, changing an int value for each one of the clones I'm making. This is the code I came up with:

```
public void fixAndSave(){
    for(int i = 1; i <= NUM_EXEC; i++){
        InputData custom = new InputData(primitive);
        for (Section s : custom.getSections()){
            if (s.getId() != 0 )
                s.setBloques(i*s.getId());
        }
        collection.add(custom);
        System.out.println("GUARDANDO DATA: " + custom.getSections().toString());

    }
    collection.forEach((InputData d) -> {
        System.out.println("DATA GUARDADO: " + d.getSections().toString());
    });
}
```

My problem is that when I check the results only the last values get saved and repeated for each of the cloned objects, so I'm guessing I'm copying the whole reference to the object somehow. How should I do it correctly so each object contains the proper information?

Here's the output for the method:

```
//This values are correct and are the ones I want
GUARDANDO DATA: [Section [id=0, length=7.5, bloques=0], Section [id=1, length=7.5, bloques=1], Section [id=2, length=7.5, bloques=2], Section [id=3, length=7.5, bloques=3]]

GUARDANDO DATA: [Section [id=0, length=7.5, bloques=0], Section [id=1, length=7.5, bloques=2], Section [id=2, length=7.5, bloques=4], Section [id=3, length=7.5, bloques=6]]

GUARDANDO DATA: [Section [id=0, length=7.5, bloques=0], Section [id=1, length=7.5, bloques=3], Section [id=2, length=7.5, bloques=6], Section [id=3, length=7.5, bloques=9]]

GUARDANDO DATA: [Section [id=0, length=7.5, bloques=0], Section [id=1, length=7.5, bloques=4], Section [id=2, length=7.5, bloques=8], Section [id=3, length=7.5, bloques=12]]

// This values are incorrect and saved in the list
DATA GUARDADO: [Section [id=0, length=7.5, bloques=0], Section [id=1, length=7.5, bloques=4], Section [id=2, length=7.5, bloques=8], Section [id=3, length=7.5, bloques=12]]

DATA GUARDADO: [Section [id=0, length=7.5, bloques=0], Section [id=1, length=7.5, bloques=4], Section [id=2, length=7.5, bloques=8], Section [id=3, length=7.5, bloques=12]]

DATA GUARDADO: [Section [id=0, length=7.5, bloques=0], Section [id=1, length=7.5, bloques=4], Section [id=2, length=7.5, bloques=8], Section [id=3, length=7.5, bloques=12]]

DATA GUARDADO: [Section [id=0, length=7.5, bloques=0], Section [id=1, length=7.5, bloques=4], Section [id=2, length=7.5, bloques=8], Section [id=3, length=7.5, bloques=12]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a deep copy that takes also into consideration the fields returned by `getSections()`  as you invoke that :

```
InputData custom = new InputData(primitive);
```

It could look like :

```
public InputData(OutputData outputData){
     // ...
     List<Section> copiedSections = new ArrayList<>();
     for (Section section : outputData.getSections()){
           Section copiedSection = new Section(section); // copy constructor
           copiedSections.add(copiedSection);
     }
     this.sections = copiedSections;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly like `dvidxxx` answer but using `java-8` streams.

```
List<Section> sections = outputData.getSections().stream()
             .map(Section::new)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```